# How to link Ui Path orchestrator with Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, azure-web-app-service, elastic-stack, uipath, uipath-orchestrator

We have UiPath installed on Azure app service, we need to link UiPath Orchestrator to Kibana in order to visualise logs.
Can someone explain/detail the steps needed to get the logs into Kibana

Answer (score 0):

So for this you need a bit of understanding of how Kibana works. Kibana is actually a visualisation tool for elasticsearch. So you're question should be more along the lines of how do I link UiPath Orchestrator to Elastic Search.

UiPath have some pretty comprehensive documentation at https://docs.uipath.com/orchestrator

I believe you have to edit the web.config file for Orchestrator with something along the lines of this

```
<target name="serverElasticBuffer" xsi:type="BufferingWrapper" flushTimeout="5000">
    <target xsi:type="ElasticSearch" name="serverElastic" uri="http://localhost:9200" index="serverdiagnostics-${date:format=yyyy.MM}" documentType="logEvent" includeAllProperties="true" layout="${machinename} ${message}" />
</target>
```